# XCode linker cannot find WebRTC symbols

Tags: objective-c, webrtc, objective-c++, webrtc-ios

I'm trying to link WebRTC's `framework_objc` compiled from source code to existing C++ project.

When I try to pass the native video encoder or decoder factory, exactly as it done in the example:

```
media_deps.video_encoder_factory = webrtc::ObjCToNativeVideoEncoderFactory(
         [[RTC_OBJC_TYPE(RTCDefaultVideoEncoderFactory) alloc] init]);
```

I'm getting this error on linking stage:

`Undefined symbol: webrtc::ObjCToNativeVideoEncoderFactory(id<RTCVideoEncoderFactory>)`

`rtc_enable_objc_symbol_export=true` argument is set, so all the ObjC symbols are exported and here  there are not any errors

Comment: What target do you have the framework built for? How did you build it? How do you include it in your project?